# debugging golang in intellij - not finding relative files

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I'm working on a golang project that has to read files from a sub directory...

When debugging my program it (not sure what `it` is yet) is unable to locate the files when provided a relative path. Im using `io.util.ReadFile(RELATIVE_PATH)` for this operation.

This problem doesn't occur when running the program from the terminal.

This has lead me to believe intellij does something behind the scenes debugging/running where it messes with the directory structure (moves it into a temporary location?). If this is the case, how would I go about configuring intellij so that the sub directories are included in the magic or removing the magic so the program is debugged from the directory it lives in.

I'm new to golang/intellij so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean providing the relative path to a go file to compile, or are you importing packages via relative paths?

Comment: I updated the question to provide clarity

Comment: The relative path to a file is not relative to the source, but to where you run the binary. Print the working directory (`os.Getwd()`) from the program and you can see where it's run. Instead of relying on relative paths, you should provide a way to find the files via an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

Click on "Edit Configurations"

[image]

and change the "Working directory" path to where your program should "live in".

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, the plugin is very flexible with the run configuration, you have to point it to where the "current working directory" of your app should be in (which can be different than where the file / app is stored).

Comment: What about when your program needs to access files outside your working directory? like `../cmd/otherdirectory/files/file.txt`. Changing the configuration *Run kind* to _Directory_ does not work then. Any ideas?